# No start on 2002 GMC Savanna 1500

Tags: fuel-system, gmc, savanna

When I try to start it it will not start I was told to push the gas and it doesn't do anything at all. I replaced the alternator and got a new battery. We have been having this problem for over a month now and we replaced the alternator twice because the mechanic kept saying that was the problem.

Comment: Welcome to the site! We're glad you're here. Hopefully we'll be able to help! Can you give us a bit more info? Does the Savanna actually crank over and not start? (Typically called a "cranks, no start" situation). How many miles on it? Are there any codes you might have had pulled? Usually if a car doesn't start, the alternator is the last place I'd look for an issue, which makes me wonder. Anything else you can provide would be greatly appreciated!